# Fix the SQL Server R-Service (in-database) installation error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have reset my windows 10 machine and tried to install SQL server 2016 developer edition. Everything else installed except the the **R-Service (In-Database )**. it has thrown the following error. But I have refreshed the machine last night, reset it with "Keep person files and folders" option, I'm using windows 10 home edition.

Error:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Setup
> The following error has occurred:
> An error occurred while creating local user account MSSQLSERVER01. The account already exists.
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.1711.0&EvtType=0xCE8B67C5%25400x92D6C0DE%25401392%25405

The link it provides is not helpful and its not directing to a knowledge base.

How do I fix this issue, do I have to uninstall the installed SQL Server and reinstall all again?

[image]

Comment: Maybe delete the user and start again: Command line `net user MSSQLSERVER01 /delete`. This should really be on [sf]

Comment: @Charlieface i just discovered by running net user ( as mentioned above ) i have 25 MSSQLServer accounts starting from MSSQLServer01 to 25

Comment: @Charlieface it removed the MSSQLServer01 but now it complains about existing user MSSQLServer02 ... so which account i need to keep and which accounts i need to remove that related to SQL server and its services?

Comment: Probably all of them. And uninstall SQL Server and start again

Comment: @Charlieface i have removed all MSSQLServer01-25 users but i wanna check if SQL works without reinstalling it ( mind its time consuming )...i will update after installing SQL Server Management Studio to see it SQL server works as it should be